# Implement Nesterov's acceleration for SVM

Tags: r, self-study, optimization, svm, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement Nestrov's acceleration gradient descent for SVM. The objective function I need to minimize is $$\frac{1}{2}\lVert Au-Bv\rVert_2^2$$ with constraints $\sum_{i}u_i=\sum_{j}v_j=1$ and elements of both $u$ and $v$ are non-negative. The matrix $A$ contains observations that have the label +1 and matrix $B$ contains observations that have the label -1.

My implementation never converges to the optimal point. How should I correct my code to get the optimal point?

```
# Projected gradient descent with constraints sum x_i=1 and x>=0
# apply Nesterov's sequence to find the optimal point
proj_gd_nesterov <- function(train, stepsize = 0.0001, tol = 1e-4) {
  # training data has size m by n
  # m is the number of variables
  # n is the number of samples
  
  A <- train$A; B <- train$B
  Asize <- dim(A); Bsize <- dim(B)
  
  n1 <- Asize[2]; n2 <- Bsize[2]
  
  # initialization
  u <- rnorm(n1); v <- rnorm(n2)
  u.old <- u; v.old <- v
  
  a0 <- 0; a1 <- 0.5*(1+sqrt(4*a0^2+1))
  diff.new <- 1; diff.old <- 2;
  iter <- 1
  
  while(abs(diff.old - diff.new) > tol) {
    # Nesterov's method
    tr <- (a0 - 1)/a1; a0 <- a1; a1 <- 0.5*(1+sqrt(4*a0^2+1))
    yu <- u + tr*(u - u.old)
    yv <- v + tr*(v - v.old)
    
    u.old <- u; v.old <- v

    # compute gradient
    gu <- (t(A)%*%(A%*%yu - B%*%yv))
    gv <- -(t(B)%*%(A%*%yu - B%*%yv))
    
    # elements of u and v are non-negative
    u <- pmax(yu - stepsize*gu, 0)
    v <- pmax(yv - stepsize*gv, 0)
    
    # the sum of u and the sum of v are one
    u <- u/sum(u)
    v <- v/sum(v)
    
    iter <- iter + 1
    diff.old <- diff.new
    diff.new <- 0.5*norm(A%*%u-B%*%v, type = "2")^2
    
    if(iter > 50000) {
      return(cbind(u, v))
    }
  }
  return(cbind(u, v))
}

optimals <- proj_gd_nesterov(train)

u <- optimals[,1]
v <- optimals[,2]

which(u == 1)
which(v == 1)

predictions <- rbind(data.frame(train=t(train$A), lab = 1), 
                 data.frame(train=t(train$B), lab = -1))

plot(predictions$train.1, predictions$train.2, col = predictions$lab + 2)
points(rbind(t(train$A%*%u), t(train$B%*%v)), col = "red")
```